# What should go into default case of a switch statement inside a Factory Method?

Tags: php, switch-statement, default, factory, factory-pattern

Factory method works great when all my object creation parameters are well-defined.  However, working with legacy code, the default seems to be to 'fail silently' or write code constructs that prevent invalid data ever reaching the factory method.

What typically goes into the `default:` case of a switch statement inside a Factory Method?

Example below...

```
class Factory
{

    function getObject($param)
    {
        switch ($param)
        {
            case 'a':
                return new A();
            case 'b':
                return new B();
            default:

                //OPTION 1
                //break code execution?  Sometimes it's not desirable
                //especially in production code as introducing an
                //Exception breaks previous legacy code behavior
                throw new \RuntimeException($message, $code, $previous);

                //OPTION 2
                //fail silently? - sometimes that's the desired behavior
                //dummy object is created does nothing, and is then 
                //discarded and code execution goes on, but creating 
                //a dummy object does not seems like the right way to address the issue
                return new fakeDummyObject(); 

                //OPTION 3
                //3rd way is to construct code that never reaches 
                //default:; switch statement.  This requires
                //more work on the legacy code side
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You code  `return new fakeDummyObject(); ` never run, because `throw new exception` steping to catch section, you can use `try { } catch {}` for catching exception and write to log.

Comment: I meant them as exclusive options - Option 1, Option 2, Option 3, one of them can be used at any one time, but not more than one together.  My question about which option is best, or if I am going about solving the problem incorrectly in the first place

Comment: I correct understand, You want `getClass('a'); getClass('a');getClass('a')` return one instance object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw an `InvalidArgumentException`. Someone’s trying to instantiate a type of object that your factory doesn’t know about.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand it is one of those times where using an `Exception` is allowed due to an exceptional circumstance of supplying rogue 'raw material' to the factory.

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand

```
class Factory
{

    private $_classes = array();

    function getObject($param,$constParam = null)
    {
        //check exist object exist
        if(isset($this->_classes[$param])) {
            return $this->_classes[$param];
        } 

        $className =  strtoupper($param);
        //check class exist
        if(!class_exists($className)) {
            return new fakeClass(); //or exception
        }

        // if don't passed params to construct
        if(is_null($constParam)) {
           $this->_classes[$param] = new $className();
           return $this->_classes[$param];
        }

        // else params passed to construct
        $this->_classes[$param] = new $className($constParam);
        return $this->_classes[$param];
    }
}
```

It's primitive realization function getter for object... If I correct understand you.